# Reference request in Circuit and Signals for Computational Neuroscience

Tags: reference-request, theoretical-neuroscience, neural-network, signal-detection

In the area of computational neuroscience, there are basic theories from electric circuits and signal processing to be applied. For background study, which reference will be more suitable ?

Personally, I don't have any background knowledge in circuit, or signals.

(Cited by Dayan's book in Theoretical Neuroscience)

"Circuits, Signals and Systems" , William M. Siebert

This book seems contains both electric circuits and signal processing, but maybe not from the ground.

Or combination or following two books

"Signals and System", Oppenheim

"Foundations of Analog and Digital Electronic Circuits", Agarwal

These two are much heavier than Siebert's, they are good ones, but is it necessary to thoroughly read these two complete detailed books for computational neuroscience ?

Answer (score 3):

[*Signals and System*](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/academic/product/0,3110,0138147574,00.html) by Oppenheim (and others) was developed while he was teaching [6.003](http://student.mit.edu/catalog/m6a.html#6.003) at MIT. Similarly [*Foundations of Analog and Digital Electronic Circuits*](https://www.elsevier.com/books/foundations-of-analog-and-digital-electronic-circuits/agarwal/978-1-55860-735-4) by Agarwal (and others) was developed while he was teaching [6.002](http://student.mit.edu/catalog/m6a.html#6.002) at MIT. [*Circuits, Signals and Systems*](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/circuits-signals-and-systems) by Siebert was written while he was teaching at MIT. Siebert was before my time, but I believe [6.002](http://student.mit.edu/catalog/m6a.html#6.002) and [6.003](http://student.mit.edu/catalog/m6a.html#6.003) where separate even when he was teaching and that despite the name, there is not much circuits in the book. I would suggest the Oppenheim book over the Siebert book, purely because it is newer, but unless you have an EE background, there are probably better references.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a strong background in circuits & signals, I highly recommend:

Circuits, Signals, and Systems for Bioengineers: A MATLAB-Based Introduction (Biomedical Engineering) by John Semmlow (Mar 21, 2005).

You can also grab some Schaum's Outlines along the way if you want added practice.
And if you enjoy the circuits section, grab an electronics kit at Makershed or Pololu.